# About construction of homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space and for every $y\in X$, $g_y:X\to X$ be a homeomorphism. Define $f:X\to X$ by $f(x)= g_x(x)$. Can we say that $f$ be a homeomorphism?

Please help me to know it.

Comment: Is there no constraint on $g_y$ other than that it is a homeomorphism from $X$ to itself? For example, the way you stated the problem, $g_y$ is chosen independent of $y$; is that your intention?

Comment: @LeeMosher, In my research I know that  there is a homeomorphism $H:X\to X$  and a family of homeomorphisms $\{g_y\}_{y\in X}$ on compact metric space $(X, d)$ such that for every $x\in X$ and every $y\in X$ we have $d(H(x), g_y(x))<\epsilon$, this means that $d_{C^0}(H, g_y)<\epsilon$.

Comment: I need to construct a homeomorphism $f:X\to X$ such that for every  $z\in X$ there is $y\in X$ with $f(z)=g_y(y)$.

Comment: That is a constraint on $f$, not on $g_y$.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Let $X=[0,1]$ with the subspace topology and let $g_y$ be the identity for $y\neq 0$ and $g_0(x)=1-x$. Then $f^{-1}((1/2,1])=\{0\}\cup(1/2,1]$ which is not open, so the map $f$ is not even continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Take $X=\Bbb S^1$ (or any nontrivial compact metrizable topological group) and $g_y$ defined by $g_y(x):=xy^{-1}$. Then $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in X$, so you don't have a homeomorphism.